# Not getting proper animation

Tags: java, android, animation

In my project, I need to create animation, in which one image button is moving from bottom to up. I created the Animation with the help of ObjectAnimator class, but problem is that i am giving the values in float numbers, but when I am trying it on different devices(7 inch Tablet and different hdpi phones), the animation is not proper. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create one anim folder in res and create one xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

       <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-35%p"
        android:duration="500" 
        />
</set>
```

and use this animation in your java code like this.

```
Animation slideout;

slideout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.yourxmlfile);
slideout.setAnimationListener(this);
view.startAnimation(slideout);
```

and implement AnimationListener to your activity. try this.

Comment: i tried it already, and it is working also but not for all types of devices, i mean on different devices, the imagebutton is not going to a particular place. On one phone it is working perfectly but on 7 inch tablet it is not going up to perfect place, it is stopping in mid.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to get the height and width of your device in run time like this

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    hight = (float) (display.getHeight() / 2);
```

after getting height then use this code for object animator

```
final ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myimageview[id],
                "translationY", hight);
```

and then start your animation

```
oa.start();
```

Comment: It's not working for me. When i used this code, my imageButton is not movig. please help me

Comment: use hieght as negitive final ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myimageview[id],
                "translationY", -hight);

Comment: use negitive height add (-) sign befor height like this -height

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In onCreate() of your activity write `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);`

In res folder,create anim folder and copy these two files :

slide_in_up.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

slide_out_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" 
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Hope this helps.